# Trying to find python numpy indexes with more than 2 logical conditions

Tags: python, numpy, logic, where-clause, logical-operators

Why does

```
w = data[np.where(np.logical_and(data['RA']>=(ra_in-0.1), data['RA']<=(ra_in+0.1)))]
```

work, but

```
w = data[np.where(np.logical_and(data['RA']>=(ra_in-0.1), data['RA']<=(ra_in+0.1), data['DEC']>=(dec_in-0.1), data['DEC']<=(dec_in+0.1)  ))]
```

doesn't???
This gives an "ValueError: invalid number of arguments" error. 
The 'in' values are floats; the data are numpy.ndarrays.

Comment: Because `logical_and` takes two such vectors? All the remaining parameters are specifications on how to process the and.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [**documentation of `numpy.logical_and`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logical_and.html) says:

> ```
> numpy.logical_and(x1, x2, /, out=None, *, where=True, casting='same_kind', order='K', dtype=None, subok=True[, signature, extobj])
> ```

As you can see, except for additional parameters on *how* to perform the `logical_and` on the two *array-like* objects `x1` and `x2`, there is no place for additional array-like objects. So in short **`logical_and` only performs the logical and over two arrays**.

You can **use a cascade** of `logica_and`s to perform the requested operation:

```
data[np.where(
    np.logical_and(
        np.logical_and(data['RA']>=(ra_in-0.1), data['RA']<=(ra_in+0.1),
        np.logical_and(data['DEC']>=(dec_in-0.1), data['DEC']<=(dec_in+0.1)
    ))]
```

So here we convert the invalid <s>`logical_and(A,B,C,D)`</s> into `logical_and(logical_and(A,B),logical_and(C,D))`.

Furthermore you can use the more elegant **logical and `&`**:

```
data[np.where(
    (data['RA']>=(ra_in-0.1)) & (data['RA']<=(ra_in+0.1)) & (data['DEC']>=(dec_in-0.1)) & (data['DEC']<=(dec_in+0.1))
    )]
```

Note that since `&` binds with higher priority, you need to **add brackets**. Note that however, we still have some cascading, since:

```
(data['RA']>=(ra_in-0.1)) & (data['RA']<=(ra_in+0.1)) & (data['DEC']>=(dec_in-0.1)) & (data['DEC']<=(dec_in+0.1))
```

is equivalent to:

```
(((data['RA']>=(ra_in-0.1)) & (data['RA']<=(ra_in+0.1))) & (data['DEC']>=(dec_in-0.1))) & (data['DEC']<=(dec_in+0.1))
```

or more abstract: `A & B & C & D` is equivalent to `((A & B) & C) & D`.

Comment: Hmmm, (a) I could but (b) that code throws a syntax error, you need to close <=(ra_in+0.1)) and (dec_in+0.1)).

Comment: but, is this seriously the best way to do numpy logic? Cascades of logical_and's ??!!

Comment: @npross: no, I would not use a `logical_and` at all, unless you need some of the additional options. You can use `&`.

Comment: Nope. I get::
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-199-8839202fb04c> in <module>()
      1 data[np.where(
----> 2     data['RA']>=(ra_in-0.1) & data['RA']<=(ra_in+0.1) & data['DEC']>=(dec_in-0.1) & data['DEC']<=(dec_in+0.1)
      3     )]

TypeError: ufunc 'bitwise_and' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

Comment: @nposs: yes, but you should add brackets. The `&` operator has precedence over `<=`.

Comment: w = data[np.where(
    (data['RA']>=(ra_in-tol)) & (data['RA']<=(ra_in+tol)) & (data['DEC']>=(dec_in-tol)) & (data['DEC']<=(dec_in+tol))
    )]